# Postgres: how to add unique identifier to table

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, constraints, unique, isolation-level

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE myid
(
  nid bigserial NOT NULL,
  myid character varying NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT myid_pkey PRIMARY KEY (myid )
)
```

Now, I want to add records to this table with the following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getmyid(_myid character varying)
  RETURNS bigint AS
$BODY$ --version 1.1 2015-03-04 08:16
DECLARE
  p_nid bigint;
BEGIN
  SELECT nid INTO p_nid FROM myid WHERE myid=_myid FOR UPDATE;
  IF NOT FOUND THEN
    INSERT INTO myid(myid) VALUES(_myid) RETURNING nid INTO p_nid;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_nid;
END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Generally it works fine, but under high load, this function sometimes fails with "duplicate key value violates unique constraint "myid_pkey";
This function is called from trigger on insert on another table, and inserts are called within transaction. Isolation level is set for READ COMMITED, postgres 9.1 on Debian Wheezy.
What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Why the *if* ? What is wrong with `INSERT INTO myid(myid) VALUES( _myid) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM myid WHERE myid = _myid);` ? [can be done in plain SQL, without the need for plpgsql]

Comment: @wildplasser I was going to comment the same :)

Comment: @wildplasser: that still might result in "duplicate key value" if two sessions are doing that exactly at the same time (but I do agree it's more efficient)

Comment: Yes, it does not solve the concurrency problem (which is implicitely unsolvable). There *could* be an additional race (but I dont expect small functions like this to be preempted (?) )

Comment: I can't find such construction in PostgreSQL 9.1 manual, and your query fails with syntax error.

Comment: @Jarek try this http://pastie.org/10116141

Comment: You'd have to extend it a bit to return the `nid bigserial` surrogate. @vivek: there you go ...

Comment: @wildplasser be specific ???

Comment: Thanks! First SELECT was missing in first hint.

Answer (score 1):

I see following way how it happens.

1. Two processes(threads) call the function simultaneously with the same `myid`.
2. Both threads successfully execute `SELECT nid INTO ..` query, and see - there is no such `myid` in table now.
3. Both threads go into `IF NOT FOUND THEN`
4. Thread 1 executes `INSERT INTO myid(myid)` and commits transaction with no errors
5. Thread 2 executes `INSERT INTO myid(myid)` and fails, because same `myid` value already exists in table (PRIMARY KEY constraint).

Why Thread 2 sees other transaction committed data in own transaction ?
Because of 'non-repeatable read' phenomena, which is possible with READ COMMITTED isolation (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/transaction-iso.html).